Would 1/4 inch coating of tungsten burn off while re-entering atmosphere at 36,000ft/second?
Imagine a projectile made from lunar regolith cement, 35ft long and 1ft in diameter. It is coated with 1/4inch of tungsten. Would it survive re entry into the atmosphere at 36,000ft/second, and enter the lower atmosphere in one piece?
Currently, our astronauts experience temperatures of up to 5,000F during re-entry. The melting point of tungsten is 6,192F.
Unfortunately, tungsten also great at conducting heat, and the melting point of regolith is roughly 2,000F.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

If the tungsten doesn’t melt, does it matter if the regolith does? It’ll still be encased within the tungsten, no?

Are you presuming the standard convex heat shield shape, or are you looking for something more like a space plane? Shape matters.

Convex heat shield at the tip @RobertRapplean

Cool. Have you looked up how modern heat shields are constructed? SpaceX and the shuttle use silicate tiles for good reasons. Are you particularly attached to titianium?

How are you going to make sure that it remains oriented correctly during re-entry?  Otherwise it seems like it could break apart without any need for heat to play a part.

@controlgroup So you have a high pressure or melted regolith inside? I don't know how much pressure that is, but won't that simply burst the whole thing?

I would presume that if the tech is available to construct and launch such an orbital weapon then sufficient R&D has gone into it to make it survive internal pressures as well. Think about the tech that that would require, and then the tech that we clearly have given that we’ve launched a regolith-cored tungsten orbital weapon.

Obligatory XKCD: https://what-if.xkcd.com/28/. Especially at that size you really don't have to worry about the whole thing melting, even without a heat shield.

Astronauts do not experience temperatures of up to 5000f during re-entry. Some components of the spacecraft do, but not the astronauts inside.

@Michael The projectiles have three or four small guidance rockets. The original propulsion was provided by a cannon on the moon, and then exact targeting occurred en route to the earth. But it would be great for the plot if I could figure out a plausible excuse for the projectiles to fail during re-entry, except the three missiles(plot twist!) that are programed to explode before reentry at 200miles up, and are loaded with a device that emits an EMP. Which my hero needs to be able to stop (but how?)

As long as your regolith projectile is contained inside a tungsten shell, does it actually matter if the rock inside is molten?  If it doesn't get splattered into the air and dispersed it's still going to hit the ground like multiple tons of rock at hypersonic velocities.

@Perkins correct. In fact, having the rock melt inside is a great way to cool the casing. Latent heat.

Note:  You're looking at two and a half metric tons of tungsten to make a sealed, tube 1/4 inch thick in those dimensions.  Tungsten is heavy stuff.

More details, please.  Are you trying to destroy the enemy by "rodding" them, or just trying to move material to the planet surface?   Can you control the orientation, because if so there's no need for shielding anywhere but the bottom surface.

It is highly unlikely the 1/4" layer of tungsten would survive. Above 1000F it will start to oxidize and tungsten oxide's melting point is only 2683F. So the oxide layer will melt away leaving a fresh layer of tungsten and the process would repeat. The rate of this process is unknown so maybe a thicker coating would survive especially on the pointy end.
Again most of the heating would be on the pointy end so maybe a thicker layer (1" or more) followed by an insulating ceramic layer to prevent heat transfer to the regolith.

YES! This is exactly the kind of info I was hoping for! Thank you! Working with this, I think I can even give it enough shielding to enable me to accelerate the entry speed, because as-is the projectile is too light for the impact to make a good bang, regolith not being very heavy. Kinetic energy = 1/2 mass times velocity squared, right?

@ShannonSkaer "regolith not being very heavy" - geology isn't my strong point, but if they have that much tungsten to spare, surely they have the resources to put something a bit denser inside of it?

I feel like the reaction rate is really important for this answer, since ballistic reentry is so short a time period. Can reaction rate be estimated?

Note that there are ways to deal with the oxidation, like a thin coating of zirconium or active cooling to keep the heat shield below the melting point of the oxide, but both raise the question of why you're using tungsten in the first place. Another issue is that pure tungsten has to be monocrystalline to be easily worked, polycrystalline tungsten is highly brittle. Perhaps you're better off describing it more generically as a refractory metal heat shield...

@user111403 My idea was that the projectiles are firing from a sublunar moonbase, and the bad guys have to work primarily with the materials they can find on the moon. This is also why they can only coat part of the projectile with a denser element

If you don't mind ablating away a couple inches (4-5 cm) of the lunarcrete from the pointy end, I wouldn't even bother with the tungsten coating.
Most meteoroids that enter Earth's atmosphere either burn up (the ones no bigger than a softball, roughly) or break up in a spectacular fireball (these can be very large, like the one that exploded over Chelyabinsk a few years ago, or the one that blew down an area of forest nearly as large as Rhode Island near Tunguska in 1908).
Your artificial one, however, is much too large to completely burn up, and sturdy enough to survive the 30 seconds to a couple minutes or so (depending on entry angle) of atmospheric heating before impact.  You're not lobbing a gravel heap held together by vacuum welding and its own microscopic gravity; you're chucking a very solid object (especially if you included a good web of reinforcing steel in the concrete).  Casting in a nose cone of fully vitrified clay brick might go a way toward reducing the ablation of the ogive, but there's no reason to waste valuable (and as noted in another answer, easily oxidized) tungsten.

Good points! This is my first time using this forum, and I'm getting such better answers than I have anywhere else! Thank you!

Most meteoroids have frozen water, CO2, etc in them that can heat, turn to gas, and then increase the interior pressure. This is a major contributor to the whole blowing up thing. So if processing the regolith into a solid rock removes those, it will probably make it sturdy enough to survive to the surface.

@codeMonkey While true, I've seen simulations that don't account for internal volatiles that suggest that even a completely dry "gravel pile" meteoroid will break up due to dynamic pressure at the stagnation point forcing the leading layer apart before it can melt into a fusion crust shield.  With an atmospheric transit time running under two minutes, there isn't time for much heat penetration in the poorly-conductive material anyway.

At this re-entry speed, you were not in Low Earth Orbit, and so you might as well come straight down since you don't intend to slow down and can achieve a straight down entry with very similar delta V requirements to an oblique entry. Re-entering spacecraft do actually need to slow down and conventional rods from god live in low earth orbit where achieving a a straight down entry would require a massive delta-V. Thus, Conduction and chemical reactions matter far less for your application than for a re-entering spacecraft. Starship began re-entry at 70,000 meters, and then had to endure re-entry heating and heat soak for 13 minutes before landing. Your "spacecraft" will begin re-entry at 70,000 meters and then have to survive for 70,000 meters / 36000 feet/second = 6.4 seconds. There isn't much time for heat to conduct.
Edit: I went and looked it up. Your projectile re-enters over the course of 2.4 seconds and hits at 20,000 feet per second.
The extra delta v required is order of magnitude the earth's radius / time to fall from lunar orbit, or 16 m/s
source: https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/research_memoranda/2008/RM3475.pdf


It might be useful to estimate how much additional delta-v this approach would require. (It won't be much, but it took me some thinking to realize that, and I'm probably not the only one.) Also, it might be useful to mention that you might have to adjust the timing of the perigee-lowering burn to hit the desired target (but you'd need to time that carefully with either approach).

These rods from god are being fired from the moon, they have three or four small rockets for guidance, but they adopt their final trajectory before hitting the atmosphere, so they can punch straight through. You all are actually being way too helpful, the original story plot called for the missiles to fail re-entry, giving my hero time to do something useful.

@ShannonSkaer All that's needed to fail during reentry is to have very bad lunarcrete combined with no aeroshell at all on the nose cone.  Scientific American had an article with simulations explaining bolides back in the 1980s, I'm sure there are better ones now.  A minor engineering error leading to pressure buildup inside the pointy end of your missiles would lead to them exploding (not far above ground, but enough so they don't act like kinetic-kill devices, instead becoming shockwave producers).

@ZeissIkon Interesting! I don't want my bad guys to be too dumb though, is this a mistake that a good engineer could make? And if a projectile failed like this on a test-run, how long difficult would it be to fix the problem? I'd love a small, simple mistake that even a brilliant scientist could make, but one that's not easy to diagnose.

@ShannonSkaer If the engineer was good, but the fabrication workers weren't ("It'll be fine, letting the lunarcrete cure in vacuum -- it'll dry even faster!"), definitely.  Having bad physical data for the cured lunarcrete wouldn't even need that, and as noted, it'd be dead easy to fix by casting in a nose cone of fully vitrified brick (i.e. kiln baked regolith).  Building on a budget and having bad test data, easy to fail and then pretty easy to fix.

There is pretty much never a situation where "The vehicle unexpectedly broke up during re-entry" will be implausible in a hard sci-fi story. Re-entry is really hard. There is a risk that, if it saves the protagonist in a way that wasn't foreshadowed, it will be narratively unsatisfying.

Apollo 10's record-setting reentry speed was 36,360 ft/s. The purpose of that fast reentry was to test their heat shield, which was designed to handle 5,432°F. Apollo 10 hit the 5,000°F point on reentry.
So... technically the tungsten would work. But that's a lot of tungsten and it's kinda heavy. In other words, it would work... but it's so darned impractical. And you'd still need some serious insulation between the tungsten and the rest of the ship.
I'd look into what materials were used for Apollo 10. It was called Avcoat:

To protect the Apollo Command Module from the extreme heat of reentry, NASA chose an ablative heat shield composed of a brazed steel honeycomb substructure, a fiberglass honeycomb shell filled with phenolic epoxy resin. The shell material was designed to vaporize (ablate) as a result of atmospheric friction a process that would prevent heat from penetrating the crew compartment. (Source)

Of course, it was ablative, meaning it was consumed in part or in whole during reentry and had to be replaced, but that kind of heat would affect pretty much anything we know of after very few reentries.

According to Apollo By The Numbers, the reentry speed for all the lunar Apollo missions, including A11, was about 36000 ft/s. There would be no way for a return from the moon to be much slower than that without expending a vast amount of propellant.

@RussellBorogove You're not wrong and I appreciate you bringing it to my attention. According to the Apollo 11 radio transcript it was 10,534 fps at about 47,000 miles (40,961 nautical miles). By 6,500 miles it was 21,366 fps maxing at 36,237 fps at around 1,700 miles to spash down. That's what I get for trusting Google.

Given that the OP is describing it as a "projectile" it seems that the weight would be a feature, not a bug, and reusability is not a design consideration.

@KerrAvon2055 That's a clarification we need. You're assuming "projectile" means "weapon." Maybe, but there would still be cheaper and more efficient solutions than tungsten. The few extra kg representing the heat shield is nothing (if it's a weapon) compared to the explosive it carries. Otherwise we'd be coating our own missiles with heavy metals.  In fact, the Minuteman III missiles are coated with an ablative coating. No, I stand by my answer. There's a better way.

@KerrAvon2055 My original idea was that the projectile was a kinetic weapon, without any further need for an explosive. But the plot originally called for it to be a dud, because it's too light, and the kinetic energy depends on mass. What I want is for these projectiles to be a dud, except the three missiles(plot twist!) that are programed to explode before reentry at 200miles up, and are loaded with a device that emits an EMP. Which my hero needs to be able to stop (but how?)

@ShannonSkaer If you want a realistic solution, then the only answers that matter are those with words like ablation and ablative in them. Most worldbuilders ignore economics. No one uses a heavy and somewhat rare metal like tungsten. Start with what's already been done. Don't vary it unless you have a plot-based reason for doing it. A kinetic weapon would be more realistic with a core of lead surrounded by an ablative heat shield than tungsten.

@JBH I started with tungsten because that's what I read kinetic weapons were (in theory) made of, but I'm happy to abandon it. The bad guys on the moon have almost exclusively local materials to work with, which is why I'm thinking the body of the projectile should be mostly lunar regolith cement. I'm assuming that shipping lead to the moon to make cores for kinetic weapons would be too costly, but shipping the materials needed to make an ablative heat shields--that's more practical.
